# Connecting to Google app engine using Python on the client side

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The server as well as the client side program are to be written in Python. Can someone tell me how to use Python on the client side to communicate with the Google App Server written in Python?

Google app engine already provides a Channel API but that is on the server side and it requires JavaScript on the client side.

Will embedding JavaScript in Python help? Any other alternatives?

Using Python 2.5 and Google App Engine v 1.5.

Comment: This would be easier to answer with a more specific use case.  The answers to *How can Python communicate with a server?* are vast; see [Internet Protocols and Support](http://docs.python.org/library/internet.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered a building a restful api on the backend? Maybe [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) could help there (not sure if it runs on GAE out of the box).

There is also Python library of the Google Channel API Client side, apparently somebody reverse-engineered the protocol: https://bitbucket.org/lohre/gae_channel/overview/

Comment: Either restful or http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/180/soap-on-the-google-app-engine-platform/
Thanks for the push in the right direction ! :)